# Understanding undocumented Vue.js attributes ( Vue + Pug )

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So i was just browsing through certain vue.js code [HERE](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/tasks/task.vue#L21). and came across the following code below:

```
menu-dropdown.task-dropdown(
  v-if="!isRunningYesterdailies",
  :right="task.type === 'reward'",
  ref="taskDropdown",
  v-b-tooltip.hover.top="$t('options')"
)
```

I don't quite understand this attribute `:right` that is inserted in the code ? What is it doing and what is its purpose , i am new to Vue.js , but by looking around a bit i was able to find documentation for the rest of the attributes except this attribute called `:right` ? Can anybody shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` in front of html attributes is a shorthand for the v-bind directive. what v-bind allows you to do is have a variable value to the specified html attribute.
ex: `v-bind:alt="kittenPhotoDescription"` is the same as doing `alt:"kittenPhotoDescription"`.

[Here](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Arguments) is where it's found in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Pug well, but it seems to me that the pasted Pug code creates a `menu-dropdown` element with those given attributes. `right` attribute is bound to a dynamic value from the Vue model using the `v-bind:` directive's [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) `:`.

I searched for `menu-dropdown` component's definition in the repository you linked, and find this file:
https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/ui/customMenuDropdown.vue

This is where the `right` attribute is defined as a Vue prop:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    right: Boolean,
    ...
```

You can read more about props in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).